# How to set the correct primary key to a SQL database using HTTP POST?

Tags: mysql, sql, asp.net, rest, asp.net-web-api

I have a webapplication that will write to a database using HTTP POST. The database is allready populated with data and have PK set to ID. When I do the HTTP POST to Web API that again writes to database. What is best practise when it comes to assigning the correct and unique primary key along with it's data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best pratice for do that is set primary key as INT AUTOINCREMENT and when you run the INSERT query does not specify the primary key and this is automatically set, this ensures you to be unique.

Comment: That's it. Thank you. :)